# What is the difference between NameError and AttributeError in Python?

Tags: python, exception

What is the diffference between those 2 types of errors? When to use each one of them?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.python/tA6pTKnawgY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attributes are properties of functions or classes or modules, and if a property is not found then it raises `attribute error`.

`NameError` are related to variables.

```
>>> x=2
>>> y=3
>>> z    #z is not defined so NameError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#136>", line 1, in <module>
    z
NameError: name 'z' is not defined

>>> def f():pass

>>> f.x=2 #define an attribue of f
>>> f.x
2
>>> f.y   #f has no attribute named y

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#141>", line 1, in <module>
    f.y
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'y'

>>> import math   #a module  

>>> math.sin(90) #sin() is an attribute of math
0.8939966636005579

>>> math.cosx(90)  #but cosx() is not an attribute of math

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#145>", line 1, in <module>
    math.cosx(90)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cosx'
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html) I think the text is pretty self explanatory.

**NameError**
Raised when a local or global name is not found. This applies only to unqualified names. The   associated value is an error message that includes the name that could not be found.

**AttributeError**
Raised when an attribute reference (see Attribute references) or assignment fails. (When an object does not support attribute references or attribute assignments at all, TypeError is raised.)

In you example above the reference to `z` raises `NameError` as you are trying to access an unqualified name (either local or global)

In you last example `math.cosx` is a dotted access (attribute reference) in this case is an attribute of the math module and thus `AttributeError` is raised.

Answer (score 0):

A name is raised by Python if you are trying to access a variable that has not been defined or assigned before. An AttributeError is raised when you are trying to access an instance variable of an instance that is not assigned or defined earlier.

See

http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html